# Less pixelated plots in RMarkdown2

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

I want to plot a `qplot() + geom_smooth()` using a knitr code chunk in an `.Rmd` document that I am compiling as an ioslides presentation, and I want less pixelation. I've played with `ggsave()` and inserting the resulting `.png` using `![image][id]`, but of course the image is massive. Can I change the image size within the RMarkdown image tag? Is there some more optimal solution? Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your Q to include a minimum reproducible example of your problem. As a possible solution, have you tried including your image in `svg` format instead of `png`?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `dev` to something scalable:

```
opts_chunk$set(
    dev = c('png', 'postscript') # produce both png and ps versions
);
```